# Concerning the omnipresence of hyper-elliptic curves in the construction of examples

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, hyperelliptic-curves

**Vague rambling:** I hate asking these types of questions, but I feel that I would benefit immensely from hearing some discussion of the use of hyperelliptic curves in constructing certain examples. What do I mean? Of course, as mathematicians, and especially as (aspiring) algebraic geometers, either while reading, examples are essential. Often times, however, hyperelliptic curves are mentioned. They are mentioned so often (from what I see) that they must have some property that is very useful when trying to construct examples.

---

**Let us consider an actual instance of this:** Following Campana's survey on **special manifolds**, define a **Bogomolov sheaf** to be a saturated, coherent subsheaf $\mathcal{L} \subset \Omega_X^p$ of rank one over a compact Kähler manifold $X$ such that the Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X, \mathcal{L})=p>0$. The manifold $X$ is said to be **special** if $X$ admits no Bogomolov sheaves.

---

**We'll construct an example of a Bogomolov sheaf as follows:** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and $\tau$ a translation of order $2$ on $E$. Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve with an involution $\eta$. Set $X : = (E \times C)/\langle \tau, \eta \rangle$ and let $f : X \to B$ be the Moishezon--Iitaka map onto some curve $B$. The saturation of $f^{\ast}K_B$ in $\Omega_X^1$ has Kodaira dimension $\kappa(X, f^{\ast}K_B)=1$ and is therefore a Bogomolov sheaf. In fact, it is the only one on $X$.

---

**Question:** What properties do hyperelliptic curves have that make them useful in the construction of examples?

---

*Feel free to downvote my question if this question is better suited for math.stackexchange. The reason for posting the problem to overflow is that the motivation is clearly at the level of research mathematics. And the question is, fundamentally, one of motivation.*

Comment: Properties besides being very explicit?.

Comment: @DonuArapura From a geometric perspective, I find elliptic curves much more explicit: they are flat and have genus $1$!

Comment: @DonuArapura I will try to be more precise in my question. Again, I apologize for the vague nature of the question. It clearly reflects my lack of understanding of hyperelliptic curves.

Comment: If you want to get your hands on a higher genus curve for whatever reason, then a hyperelliptic curve is a good thing to look at: the $1$-forms on it is easy to describe, Mumford gave an explicit construction of its Jacobian...

Comment: There's also the fact that every genus 2 curve is hyperelliptic, so you're getting another whole genus. OTOH, there are certainly theorems along the lines of "If C is hyperelliptic, then X is true, otherwise Y is true." A larger class of curves that is easier to deal with are cyclic covers of $\mathbb P^1$ (often called "super-elliptic curves"). Also, by analogy if you've studied number theory, after $\mathbb Q$, it's very instructive to study quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$; replace $\mathbb Q$ with $k(T)$, voila, you have hyperelliptic function fields.

Comment: Also, hyperelliptic (and superelliptic) curves have (lots of) automorphisms. Automorphisms can be really useful!

Comment: @DonuArapura Thank you

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thank you

Comment: @Asvin Thank you! Do you have an illustrative example?

Comment: Superelliptic curves (in characteristic not dividing the degree of the cover) have the form $$Y^n=f(X).$$ They thus admit automorphisms $(X,Y)\to(X,\zeta Y)$, where $\zeta$ is an $n$th root of unity. More intrinsically, since there is a map $C\to\mathbb P^1$ that is Galois with group $G\cong\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, the elements of $G$ are automorphisms of $C$. And depending on the shape of $f(X)$, it's possible for $\operatorname{Aut}(C)$ to be even larger.

Comment: Besides the fact that one can gets his/her hands on hyper-elliptic curves, it is worth noticing that they are general enough to be interesting for various reasons and in many different situations.

Comment: Hyperelliptic curves are unique among curves of general type in that their canonical bundle is not very ample; this property has always seemed particularly relevant to me. It might also be relevant that hyperelliptic curves are not complete intersections, so they are an explicit way of getting around a property that is "hard to avoid" most of the time.